# Get Count property of ICollectionView

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, collections, observablecollection

I have ICollectionView

```
private ICollectionView _snapshotList;

    public ICollectionView SnapshotList {
        get { return _snapshotList; }
    }
```

which im setting in ViewModel constructor, where `this.smapshotListModel.SnapshotItems` returns ObservableCollection

```
_snapshotList = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.snapshotListModel.SnapshotItems);
        _snapshotList.Filter = ErrorMsgFilter;
        _snapshotList.CollectionChanged += OnCollectionChanged;
```

And later in collectionChanged event im trying to get count of items in this collection,

```
        void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) {
        this.ItemCount = _snapshotList.Count();
    }
```

But its throwing error, that there is no Definition for Count method.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try like this;

```
_snapshotList.Cast<object>().Count();
```

`ICollectionView` implements `IEnumarable` but it doesn't implement `IEnumerable<TSource>` like `List<TSource>`, `HashSet<TSource>` etc. So, `ICollectionView` doesn't have a generic type and we have to cast it to `IEnumerable<object>` once to enable `Count()` method.